# sharepoint user profile properties Client Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest

im trying to get user profile picture in my Cilent Web Part but I get a error massage (`_spPageContextInfo` is `undefined`).

I'm useing REST API

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            GetCurrentUser();

            function GetCurrentUser() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureUrl",
                    type: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var userName = data.d.DisplayName;
                        var picUrl = data.d.PictureUrl;
                        $('#bild').attr('src', picUrl);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

are there other ways to solve it ? would be appreciated if you could help me solve it

Comment: Looks like you are executing the code not in an SP Dom Context. `_spPageContextInfo` is directly written on the page via SSOM so you can use it nearly immediately. What do you mean by ClientWebPart? An SP Hosted APP?

Comment: ClientWebPart is a Web Part Page

Comment: can i use something other than _spPageContextInfo??

Comment: WebPart-Page is the layout you are using for your page.The `_spPageContextInfo` is the only suitable object to get the `siteAbsoluteUrl`. If this is not working for you you simply do something wrong.

Comment: you can test run my code and see if you get error

Comment: Did you use app part or Content Editor Web Part?

Comment: I have tested run this code and got the link to the picture (working correctly) but it's not displayed. the picture is broken SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js'); var userProfileProperties; function getUserProperties() { var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext); userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties(); clientContext.load(userProfileProperties); clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail); } function onRequestSuccess() { var PIC = u

Answer (score 0):

Surround *GetCurrentUser* call with `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` to ensure *_spPageContextInfo* exists before you use it. You should be able to have the actual function code outside *ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded* for clarity.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function ()
{
    GetCurrentUser();
}, "sp.js");
```

Comment: I get same error massage (_spPageContextInfo is undefined)